# WebSocket to Kafka Topic Scala API

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have a requirement where I have WebSocket as the data source and want to push data from WebSocket into Kafka topic for further processing. I am not sure if any apis is there in scala to achieve it. So stuck with this to get start with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my hobby projects ([play-binding-petstore](https://github.com/pme123/play-binding-petstore)) I used:

**[Alpakka Kafka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html)**

[PathMsgProducer.scala](https://github.com/pme123/play-binding-petstore/blob/master/server/app/pme123/petstore/server/control/PathMsgProducer.scala) does what you are asking for - takes the input from a websocket and pushing it to `Kafka`.

Here is how to push a message to `Kafka`:

```
ProducerMessage.Message(
          new ProducerRecord(comps.config.kafkaWsPathMsgTopic, msg.username, msg.route),
          "passThrough"
        )
```

See `PathMsgProducer.scala` on how to use it in the Websocket.

Comment: can you advice how this can be done on Java.. basically, I am looking at a connector (which I need to customize a wee bit) to read from websockets and write into a topic..

Comment: Everything from akka is available for Scala and Java - just check the documentation where you can switch to Java.