# Kafka: Connector to consume data from websockets and push to topic

Tags: websocket, apache-kafka

We have a data flow pipeline where logs are sent from a websocket endpoint, which need to be pushed to Splunk after doing simple data enhancing (password masking etc).

I was checking if Kafka can be used for this because the volumes are really high. So, the possible flow is:

Websocket Endpoint ---------***some-wss-connector***--------> Kafka Topic --------*splunk-connector*----------> Splunk

I found the connector for pushing to Splunk at: https://github.com/splunk/kafka-connect-splunk and it works good.

Need help in the other connector (bolded above) to read from websocket endpoints in Kafka and push to a topic. Has anyone worked on something similar please? Please advice.

NOTE: I've looked at [WebSocket to Kafka Topic Scala API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511583/websocket-to-kafka-topic-scala-api) but that's using Akka (with Scala) but I am afraid Akka/Scala is not part of our enterprise at this moment.

Thanks in advance.
Vinay

Comment: Seen? https://github.com/Effyis/kafka2websocket

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you´ll need some sort of adapter application (be it in the form of kafka connect or not).
My idea is to write a small spring boot application which implements a websocket client, see this link to get an idea of how (scroll a bit down):
 https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-spring-websocket-server-and-client/

Then after that, you can push the messages received via websocket to apache kafka using spring kafka, which works fine in my experience: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

For Serialization from SpringBoot App to Kafka you *can* user JSON, however I recommmend the full bells and whistles with AVRO and a schema registry: https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/index.html

The main drawback of this idea is the fact that you get another application you need to implement, maintain, deploy and scale.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks ckmuun.. although the approach is workable, there is a lot of resistance for adding new technology stack (esp. with maintenance and hosting as you said) in the enterprise :( .. since Kafka is already part of it, I was hoping someone must've done something with a connector...

Comment: Take a look at cricket007´s comment, it may solve your problem with a little tweaking. However, what you can do is implementing a new Kafka Connector, see the developer guide here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html